# Can we split and join the large text files

Tags: filesplitting

I need to split large text files around 10 GB  into multiple text files (mostly 1gb files) 
and join those same text files into one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `split` command then try this,

**Example:**

```
split -b1024 your_large_file.txt sample_prefix
```

It will split the large file and produce the list of files with 1024 bytes.

**Join:**

```
cat sample_prefixaa sample_prefixab sample_prefixac > final_org_largefile.txt
```

It will concatenate the contents of the spitted files and produce the single file.

Note: Linux will have `split` command. But, I don't know about `GNUwin32`.

Comment: Thanks! Can we do this same scenario with csplit

Comment: In Join is that mandatory to give file name like `sample_prefixaa` i mean i want to join like `*.*`. Because i don't know that how many files split command may split

Comment: @Raj, Not like that. It is a spitted filenames. But, It should be in the order. If you see the example, the last argument of `split` command is prefix of filename for splitting files. Prefix name can be anything.

Comment: I got that! but i want to join like `*.*`. Because i don't know that how many files split command may split

Comment: @Raj, If you split the file by 1GB, then you will have only 10 files.

Comment: Ya but if some time the files comes abound 12 gb then how can i get the perfect result in runtime

Comment: @Raj, Like this: `sample_prefix.*`

Comment: used the `-u` or `-unbuffered` option on your sed with huge file to avoid memory problem